# encode three integers into single integer

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have to encode 3 numbers into the same integer.

I have these 3 measurements

```
uint256 carLength;
uint256 carWidth;
uint256 carDepth;
```

and i want to encode these 3 numbers into the same integer with the possibility to decode. My problem is that I'm not very experienced at this low level.

i think about functions like this

```
function encodeNumbers(uint256 a, uint256 b, uint256 c) public view returns(uint256);

function decodeNumber(uint256) public view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256);
```

advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Why do you want to combine the three integers into one? Is it to save space and the related gas costs of `SSTORE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take each of `a,b,c` to be 32 bits (4 bytes, or a standard int in most languages) you can do it with some simple bitshifting.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Test {
    function encodeNumbers(uint256 a, uint256 b, uint256 c) public view returns(uint256 encoded) {
        encoded |= (a << 64);
        encoded |= (b << 32);
        encoded |= (c);
        return encoded;
    }

    function decodeNumber(uint256 encoded) public view returns (uint256 a, uint256 b, uint256 c) {
        a = encoded >> 64;
        b = (encoded << 192) >> 224;
        c = (encoded << 224) >> 224;
        return;
    }


}
```

When encoding, we simply move the numbers into sequential 32-bit sections. When decoding, we do the opposite. However, in the case of b and c, we need to first blank out the other numbers by shifting left first, then shifting right.

`uint256`, as the name says, actually has 256 bits, so you could actually fit 3 numbers up to 85 bits each in there, if you really needed to.

Comment: this is valid also with negative numbers? im trying but seems not work

Comment: uint256 is unsigned, it has no negative numbers

Comment: You will need to use int256 if you want negative numbers, but the conversion is a bit different since you need to sign extend. There are plenty of C/C++ examples of handling that on Google and Stack Overflow, the same concept applies here

Comment: If the goal is just to reduce gas costs when storing the values, you can just put them in a `struct` and let the Solidity compiler do the work, e.g. `struct foo { uint8 a; uint8 b; uint8 c; }`.

Comment: @RaghavSood Thanks for sharing amazing input. Could you please point out some resources that I can follow for negative numbers? I will really appreciate it.